# How use an SVG image as a background?

Tags: css, html, svg

I must be doing something wrong. The image was exported from illustrator as an SVG and (I'm not sure whether this is relevant or not) it does have some pixel data in it.
[Here's my JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wdW2K/).

Note that going directly to the image, it shows up just fine:
http://ykcreations.com/tv.svg

---

**Edit: This does not work in Chrome or Safari but DOES in Firefox. Webkit issue?**

Comment: It looks like it is working to me.

Comment: Works just fine for me... took a long time to load though.

Comment: Not working for me on Chrome/ubuntu but working on FF/ubuntu.

Comment: Is it possible it tries to display it before loading or something?

Comment: I assure you that the latest versions of both Chrome and Safari support SVG without plugins.  It has to do with your image file, see my answer below with an alternate SVG plugged in.

Answer (score 9):

There is a problem with your source SVG. See this updated Fiddle pointing to [a different SVG file](http://phrogz.net/svg/800x800.svg) that works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/wdW2K/2/

```css
.tv {
  background: url("http://phrogz.net/svg/800x800.svg");
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
}​
```

**Edit**: Specifically, the problem *appears* to be that WebKit does not support `<image>` in an SVG used as a background. Modifying your file minimally to change the `<image>` to reference a local (non-data-uri) file, and adding a `<circle/>`, I was able to see both the image and circle when viewing the SVG directly in Chrome, but when used as a background image only the circle was visible.

[This bug](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2011-February/290645.html) smells relevant.

Comment: I don't quite understand your edit. I also have an SVG file which does  not work as a background and I see it has inside it a big chunk of `<image>`..

Comment: @vsync What I was saying was that I pared down the example to be very simple—the `<image>` element did not use a `data:` uri, and did not use complex content—and it looked correct by itself but incorrect as a background. This was data supporting the belief that there is a bug in WebKit, and not a problem with the content.

Comment: there is a bug, I wish I could find it so I could star it.

Comment: @vsync I believe it is what I referenced: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15443

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with your image, try plugging the following into your `CSS`:

```
.tv
{
    background-image: url("http://croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/butterfly/butterfly.svg");
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}​
```

Perhaps your `SVG` is actually an `SVGZ`?  `SVGZ` files are the compressed versions of `SVG` files.  Usually you have to configure your server to handle that, but FF may just be able to deal with the compressed versions.

**EDIT**
See Phrogz's answer below (possibly above by the time you read this); it covers this and gives a better explanation.

Comment: You can see from the HTTP response headers that the data is not gzipped.

Comment: Would the header indicate if the file WAS zipped but not properly flagged as zipped? (I ask only because I honestly don't know these things)

Comment: If that were the case then `curl http://www.ykcreations.com/tv.svg` would should binary data coming in. It does not; it shows proper encoding.

Comment: Ah, well, your answer seems to cover both things, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause is serving the SVG with the wrong MIME type.  Setting it to 'image/svg+xml' may fix the issue.

In Rails, this can be done by adding the following to config/intializers/mime_types.rb:

`Mime::Type.register 'image/svg+xml', :svg`

Comment: I fixed it for PHP using https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/serve-svg-correct-content-type/ & http://stackoverflow.com/a/37598893/1461060

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar problem with rendering svg as background image in Chrome, but everything was fine in Firefox. I found out that there was a syntax error inside my svg files exported from Adobe:

wrong xlink attribute:

```
xlink:href="data:img/png;base64
```

correct xlink attribute:

```
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64
```

Article bellow:

[Link to article from css-trick that helped me](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/svg-css-background-image-not-showing-in-chrome/)