# SVG images not showing up in Safari on OSX and iOS

Tags: css, svg, safari, mobile-safari, mime-types

Firstly I have checked all other SVG/Safari related posts including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432293/svg-in-css-backgrounds-not-showing-up-in-safari)

I have completed many experiments with SVG's trying to make them appear over the last 3-4 weeks and I have still made no progress. I have changed lines in the .htaccesss, I have tried to add the SVG images in 3 different ways none of which work.

SVG images from other sites do appear in Safari which makes the matter more confusing. I have copied these pages exactly across, hosted them on my server and they don't work again. In the Safari web inspector I have noticed a slight change in the mimetype between a SVG that will show and one that wont:

---

unfortunately not at my 10 reputations so cant share this info yet. 
It was basically, this will show:

> MIME Type:      image/svg+xml
>   Resource Type:    Image

And this will not show up:

> MIME Type:      image/svg+xml **svg**
>   Resource Type:    Image

The subtle difference is the 'svg' in the second one. This appears any time an SVG is not compatible.

---

I have contacted the hosting company and they say that it is definitely a browser issue. Please help with this, it is driving me insane at the minute as I want to begin using SVG images instead of PNG/JPEG 's. My site is [here](http://www.jimmyux.com).

Comment: You don't have a `.htaccess` file that is overriding the mime type by any chance do you?

Comment: Hi Paul, I apologise I was expecting an email alert for responses to this and didnt receive any, so didnt check. Not sure tbh. I only know of my one .htaccess file and thats in the root folder for wordpress. Where should I look?

Comment: Is there anything SVG related in that .htaccess file? If so, can you post it?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: This is what I have in my .htaccess file.

Comment: That looks okay. So that's probably not the problem.

Comment: Im absolutely baffled, I have no idea what to do now, I really do not want to go back to using PNG's after putting so much effort into trying to get away from them.

Comment: Sorry I can't help more.  There is not really enough info to go on.  Perhaps pester your hosting service people a bit more. Or ask them if they can point you at another client who is using SVGs successfully.