# React.js - background image is breaking on apple devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, background-image

I have this working background image pattern,

[image]

With this code:

```
body {
  background-image: url("assets/images/background-pattern.svg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
}
```

But in apple devices, it's breaking like this:

[image]

and sometimes like this:

[image]

Comment: Try the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22442942/1647656

Comment: @AlexGuerra thanks for the answer, but this is not a Safari issue. The apple device is using the latest Chrome =/

Comment: What are the specs of your apple device?

Comment: @Momenator it's both a 2015 and a 2016 MacBook Pro

Comment: Is there anyway you could show it online?

Comment: @Momenator I'm sorry but no, because this is after Login on a product to be released :(

Comment: You don't have to show everything, just grab the component of interest, along with the assets and paste them into jsbin or jsfiddle.