# Button with CSS SVG background image does not show up on Safari/Webkit IOS or MacOS

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, webkit

I am using IIS10 to serve web pages and ASP.NET Webforms.  I have an HTML page with a series of toolbar buttons.  These buttons have masked CSS backgrounds in SVG to present toolbar icons.

Buttons render as expected in Windows Edge (Chromium), Chrome, etc., as well as on Chrome on MacOS.  However, on MacOS Safari, WebKit pages in apps and iOS Safari and apps, the buttons render no image.  I checked the MIME type per the [SVG in CSS backgrounds not showing up in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432293/svg-in-css-backgrounds-not-showing-up-in-safari) link, and it is properly set to **image/svg+xml** for the svg file extension.  An example is shown below:

HTML:

```
    <button id="print" class="toolbarButton print hiddenMediumView" title="Print" tabindex="33" data-l10n-id="print">
        <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
    </button>
```

CSS:

```
.toolbarButton.print::before {
    -webkit-mask-image: url(images/toolbarButton-print.svg);
    -webkit-mask-image: var(--toolbarButton-print-icon);
    mask-image: url(images/toolbarButton-print.svg);
    mask-image: var(--toolbarButton-print-icon);
}
[snip]
--toolbarButton-print-icon: url(images/toolbarButton-print.svg);
```

Has anyone run into this and if so, is there a solution?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the duplicate `-webkit-mask-image` CSS tags, one with the `url`, and the other with a `var` pointing to the `url`.

The fix was to remove the second `-webkit-mask-image` with the `var` -- the masks then worked perfectly.