# Embedded <image> not rendered when using SVG as background-image

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an [SVG image with an illustration of a cloud](https://stage.ask.pekka.net/assets/weather-icons-handdrawn/svg/elements/cloud.svg).

[image]

The cloud is going to be used in several weather icons. I have [another SVG file](https://stage.ask.pekka.net/assets/weather-icons-handdrawn/svg/CLEAR_DAY.svg) that embeds the cloud illustration and adds another graphical element, a circle.

Now, this main SVG file shows up fine when I open it directly in the browser:

[image]

However, when I use the file as a `background-image`, the cloud is not rendered:

[image]

[Here's a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3yn9j27j/)

What the heck?

- It shouldn't be a relative path issue because the image shows up fine when I call the main SVG in the browser (and I tried using an absolute path to no avail)
- It's not a clipping issue - if you change the `background-size` property in the JSFiddle, you'll see the entire image area is rendered, just without the cloud.
- The cloud was generated by Adobe Illustrator and not optimized yet, but seems to look ok.

This is the main SVG's markup:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <circle cx="0" cy="-0" r="30" style="fill:red" />
      <image x="12" y="12" width="20" height="40" xlink:href="elements/cloud.svg" />
    </svg>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've tested this in Safari 9.1.2 and latest Chrome on OS X, with the same result.

Comment: This appears to be a Webkit bug, looks like I'll have to take a different path here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529857/how-use-an-svg-image-as-a-background A clear, authoritative answer would be appreciated though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All SVGs that are inserted as images (through the `img` tag or as a `background-image`) cannot reference external files. So if you have an external CSS stylesheet, a custom font, or as in your case an external image, it won't work.

The solution would be to embed the image data within the `xlink:href` attribute:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="0" cy="-0" r="30" style="fill:red" />
  <image x="12" y="12" width="20" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg%20id%3D%22Ebene_1%22%20data-name%3D%22Ebene%201%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20284%20179%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E.cls-1%7Bfill%3Anone%3B%7D.cls-2%7Bclip-path%3Aurl(%23clip-path)%3B%7D.cls-3%7Bfill%3A%23508f9e%3B%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3CclipPath%20id%3D%22clip-path%22%20transform%3D%22translate(-278.44%20-208.09)%22%3E%3Crect%20class%3D%22cls-1%22%20x%3D%22279.44%22%20y%3D%22207.09%22%20width%3D%22284%22%20height%3D%22179%22%2F%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Ctitle%3Ecloud%3C%2Ftitle%3E%3Cg%20class%3D%22cls-2%22%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22TK6tin%22%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22cls-3%22%20d%3D%22M562.44%2C302.09c-4.19%2C9-7.71%2C18.44-13.39%2C26.63-9.1%2C13.12-21.26%2C22.65-35.52%2C30.06C497.65%2C367%2C481%2C372.3%2C463.34%2C373.68c-17%2C1.33-32.1-3.68-43.58-16.9-3-3.43-4.87-2.72-7.56-.06-6%2C5.92-11.9%2C11.83-19.1%2C16.52-9.22%2C6-19.37%2C9.45-29.58%2C13a4.17%2C4.17%2C0%2C0%2C0-1.09.89h-19c-7.91-2.63-15.56-5.83-21.8-11.53a10%2C10%2C0%2C0%2C0-6.55-2.63c-15.38-1.29-32.37-10.18-35.09-28.87-0.38-2.61.39-5.62-1.56-8v-5c2.09-3.79%2C1.2-8.2%2C2.85-12.26%2C2.87-7.07%2C8.91-9.62%2C15-11.45%2C5.41-1.62%2C9.87-3%2C11.87-9%2C3.9-11.71%2C12.39-17.5%2C24.66-17.08%2C5.43%2C0.18%2C7.92-1.18%2C10.39-6.77%2C4.51-10.24%2C12-18.52%2C21.06-25.77A171.48%2C171.48%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C398.75%2C227c20.39-9.63%2C41.2-17.45%2C64.13-17.83%2C1%2C0%2C2%2C.11%2C2.55-1.06h7c2.35%2C2.26%2C5.3.64%2C7.93%2C1.21%2C13%2C2.81%2C25.88%2C6.08%2C37.28%2C13.42%2C8.3%2C5.35%2C17.12%2C10.07%2C23.36%2C18a94%2C94%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C10.57%2C17.12c4.56%2C9.4%2C9.31%2C18.73%2C10.86%2C29.24v15ZM318.12%2C365.24c1.49%2C0.13%2C1.71%2C1.24%2C2.29%2C2a37.42%2C37.42%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C25.1%2C14.71c15%2C2%2C28.63-2.48%2C41.61-9.82C397.41%2C366.3%2C405%2C357.4%2C413.92%2C350c2.08-1.74%2C3.65-2.89%2C5.66-.08%2C12.35%2C17.29%2C30.17%2C21.51%2C49.68%2C19a127.56%2C127.56%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C54.87-21c16.7-11.17%2C26.73-27.07%2C33.68-45.37%2C0.68-1.8.5-3.59%2C0.63-5.41%2C1.16-16.58-6.55-30.39-13.88-44.3a39.91%2C39.91%2C0%2C0%2C0-7.73-10.86c-13.58-12.69-28.91-22-47.27-26.37-15.43-3.68-30.69-3.42-46.1-.72-15.69%2C2.75-30.25%2C8.85-44.45%2C15.69-23.79%2C11.46-45.28%2C25.58-54.66%2C52.22a3.16%2C3.16%2C0%2C0%2C1-3.27%2C2.38c-3.81.17-7.6%2C0.73-11.42%2C1-9.24.54-15.85%2C4.7-17.71%2C13.68-1.27%2C6.13-4.13%2C9-9.56%2C10.64-1.3.39-2.6%2C0.42-3.85%2C0.75-5.69%2C1.52-11.51%2C3.66-13.65%2C9.54-4.64%2C12.77-2.74%2C26.7%2C6.27%2C37.43%2C6%2C7.19%2C14.75%2C9.64%2C23.74%2C10.93%2C0.84%2C0.12%2C1.74%2C1.26%2C2.8.06C317.92%2C368%2C316.87%2C366.61%2C318.12%2C365.24Z%22%20transform%3D%22translate(-278.44%20-208.09)%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Argh - but it makes sense from a security viewpoint I suppose. Looks like there's no way but to pull in the main SVG to the document then. Thanks! Is there an official reference to this behaviour somewhere, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the explanation in this link:
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

You need to enter the full svg code. you can get it from photoshop or online tools like this:

```
.background-img {
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30'><circle cx='15'  cy='15' r='10' /></svg>")  no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    }
```